# how to get result count group by day in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello Everyone can you please help me to resolve this

I want to get the user count day-wise, for example, I want to know how many users registers in last week

like date of

22-07-19

user count 20

23-07-19

user count 30

24-07-19

user count 10

25-07-19

user count 15

I want this result for last 7 day from today

basically, I want to show this in my chart please check the image here

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By selecting `DATE(created_at)` and grouping by that, we can get the count of users that have registered each day. We can then add a simple `where` clause, using `Carbon` to help us get the lower bounds.

Example (where `x = date` and `y = count`):

```php
User::selectRaw('DATE(created_at) as x, COUNT(*) as y')
    ->groupBy('x')
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
    ->get();
```